# Access the radio button value created by using ng-repeat

Tags: jquery, angularjs, radio-button

i have one table and first column of table is radio button. I have created using ng-repeat. on click i have to access the checked radio button value the problem i can't access the value.

```
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title mainPanelTitle">Future Appointments</h3>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="table-responsive noSwipe tableContainer" tasty-table bind-resource="futureAppointmentsMap" bind-filters="filters">
        <div class="col-sm-3 tableSearch">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm"
            placeholder="Search" ng-model="filters" value=""/>
        </div>
        <table id="tblPatientMyAppointmentsFuture" class="table table-bordered">
            <thead tasty-thead bind-not-sort-by="notSortBy"></thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="appointment in rows">
                    <td>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="rbnTagAppointment" value="{{appointment.id}}" ng-model="selectedAppointmentId">
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td ng-class="{{appointment.timeLineId!=0?'tdImage':''}}" data-title="No">
                        {{$index+1}} 
                        <img ng-if="appointment.timeLineId!=0" ng-src="img/brightfuture_logomedium.png"/>
                    </td>
                    <td data-title="Time">
                        {{changeDateFormat(appointment.date)}}<br>
                        {{appointment.time}}
                    </td>
                    <td data-title="Specialty">
                        {{appointment.specialtyId=="5"?'Pediatrics':appointment.specialty}}
                    </td>
                    <td data-title="Physician">
                        {{appointment.physicianName}}<br/>
                        {{appointment.orgName}} 
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div tasty-pagination ng-show="rows.length>0"></div>
        <div class="divNoData" ng-show="rows.length==0">
            No data available
        </div>
        <div class="text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="tabAppointmentWithImmunization()">Upload</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

in my controller.

```
 $scope.tabAppointmentWithImmunization = function() {
    console.info($scope.selectedAppointmentId);
};
```

when i print the value it shows undefined.

Comment: I fixed your html, you had a lot of unneeded closing tags (why?), you might want to copy it.

Comment: @MartijnWelker sorry it was copy paste problem...

Answer (score 0):

Remove the curly braces, no need for interpolation:

```
ng-value="appointment.id"
```

I also changed your `value` attribute to `ng-value` - in common use with `ng-repeat`.

More details here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-value if you want to bind the $scope value and also your ng-value and ng-model should be same if you want to apply two way binding.

`<input type="radio" name="rbnTagAppointment" ng-value="selectedAppointmentId" ng-model="selectedAppointmentId">`

Comment: i don't need any text to display... i Just want to access the selected radio button value.... i changed value to ng-value but its not working....

Comment: could you share me, what is the data in rows?

Comment: that doesn't matter.. the problem is when  assign the value to $scope.selectedAppointmentId it selects the corresponding radio button but when change selection the model not updating.

Comment: You are using selectedAppointmentId in the ng-repeat and i am afraid this would be the same value for each. There should be a unique value in selectedAppointmentId for each row.